# How to enable “middle” click of Apple's Magic Mouse?

Tags: mouse

Recently I bought a Magic Mouse from Apple & I want to enable the middle click to use it  in some apps like Chrome, Safari etc.

The native configuration include only left and right click, but is there any way to enable the middle click?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: not natively, you will have to outsource it to a 3rd party app. there are free ones out there worth your time

Comment: Middle Click (Free App): https://dericeira.github.io/middleclick/

Answer (score 17):

[MagicPrefs](http://magicprefs.com/) seems like the only solution currently available to enable a third button on a Magic Mouse.

From their website:

> MagicPrefs is a free application for OS X which aims to improve the
>   functionality and configuration options of the Apple Magic Mouse,
>   Magic Trackpad and the MacBook glass trackpad.
>
> It features the ability to bind a variable number of finger clicks,
>   taps, swipes, pinch and other gestures to functions like Middle Click,
>   Hold Down Both Mouse Buttons, Spaces, Expose, Dashboard, Recent
>   Applications, Tweet, Read Tweets, Google Reader etc.

Comment: MagicPrefs seems not to work with the new Apple Magic Mouse 2 (MLA02LL/A), when you try to customize the behavior of it, it shows a message indicating that the magic mouse was not detected.

Comment: Sad to say that MagicPrefs seems to have announced EOL - as High Sierra breaks functionality https://twitter.com/vladalexa/status/930055017863745536

Answer (score 17):

[BetterTouchTool](https://folivora.ai/downloads/) allows you to program a response to various gestures on the Magic Mouse, Trackpads, and other input devices.  Middle-click, and Middle-tap on the Magic Mouse are both available.

[image: BetterTouchTool Magic Mouse Gesture menu]